# PHP PDO não insere valor

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Não entendo muito bem de PHP, mas estou tentando criar uma conexão PDO.
A conexão funciona de boa, mas não insere os valores...

segue o codigo:

config

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB_NAME", "everton");

define("DB_DSN_MYSQL", 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME);
define("DB_DSN_FIREBIRD", 'firebird:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME);

date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
```

conexao

```
try {
            $this->con = new PDO(DB_DSN_MYSQL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch (PDOException $exception){
            $flag['flag'] = 'CONN_FAILED';
            die(json_encode($flag));
        }
```

inserção

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO teste (codigo, nome) VALUES (:codigo, :nome)';
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $codigo = 1;
    $nome = 'teste';

    $stmt->bindValue(':codigo', $codigo);
    $stmt->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
```

Comment: 1º Prepare, 2º Bind, 3º ??? **Execute**.

Comment: Poder me ajudar aqui//?? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/dados-com-except-n%c3%a3o-funcionam-utilizando-pdo-e-mysql

Answer (score 2):

> **$stmt->execute();**

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO teste (codigo, nome) VALUES (:codigo, :nome)';
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
$codigo = 1;
$nome = 'teste';

$stmt->bindValue(':codigo', $codigo);
$stmt->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
$stmt->execute();
```